# Understanding preg_match formula

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I anyhow got my stuff working with following line, but I really could not understand.

```
if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Desktop/test/b '$test'"),$matches))
                {
                        $x = (int) $matches[1][0]; //optionally cast to int
                        $y = (int) $matches[1][1];
                        $pcount= round((100*$x)/($x+$y),2);
                        $ncount= round((100*$y)/($x+$y),2);
                }
```

`b` is executable file, which gives result something like `x=10` and `y=20`

Can some one explain me whatever inside `if()`

Comment: What's unclear? Read [preg_match_all](http://us1.php.net/preg_match_all) PHP manual page; read Regex tuturial - there are plenty of them (type **regex tutorial** in google)

Comment: I find these to be useful tools for investigating regexes http://www.regexper.com/ and http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I hope you're sanitizing `$test` who knows what will happen when someone tries something evil

Answer (score 2):

This: `/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/` collects all `...=...` things to the $matches array.

- `[^=]` means any character except =
- `[^;@]` means any character except ; and @
- `()` means collect it into $matches explicitly

The $pcount/$ncount makes percent from the values showing theirs ratio.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern details:

```
[^=]*       # is a negated character class that means "all characters except ="
            # * is quantifier that means zero or more times
            # note that it seems more logical to replace it with + 
            # that means 1 or more times

=           # literal =

(           # open the capturing group 1
  [^;@]*    # all characters except ";" and "@", zero or more times
            # (same notice) 
)           # close the capturing group 1
```